Are there drive capacity limits for USB3 HDD docking stations?
I recently purchased a Seagate IronWolf Pro 22TB drive. I want to use it in an external USB3 docking station with a Windows 10 64 bit OS.
Is there a physical limit that affects the supported drive capacity of external docks? I see various docks that say they support 8TB, 10TB, 20TB. (Usually the 20 TB refers to a dual dock with two 10 TB drives)
My understanding is the 48 bit LBA addressing scheme that has been in use for many years supports capacity up to 128 PiB, which is a much higher limit.
Is there some other factor that limits the drive capacity of external docking stations?
What term should I search with to find docks that do not have this limit in drive capacity?

The different chipsets used for the SATA-USB interface is what I suppose the limiting factor.

Unfortunately, There can be. The limitations with the USB and/or SATA controllers have nothing to do with LBA addressing.
